# How cut one character after the dot in a shell script variables

Tags: shell

I need to remove all characters after the first one after the dot:

example:

the temperature is 28.34567 C°

I need only 28.3

I've tried with `cut -d'.' -f1` but cut all after the dot..

Thanks a lot

Comment: Which shell? `bash`, `zsh`, `ksh`, `dash`, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Bash:

```
$ var=23.123
$ [[ $var =~ [0-9]*(\.[0-9]{,1})? ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
```

Output:

```
23.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add this line to your script if you have python3+

```
python -c "print(f\"{28.34567:.1f}\")"
```

This solution rounds the result (ceil)

Output:

```
28.3
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your support, I need to use bash script, there is a production script but now I need a decimal in the temperature.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, each with its own issues.  The trivial solution is `sed`.  Something like:

```
$ echo "the temperature is 28.37567 C°" | sed -e 's/\([[:digit:]]\.[0-9]\)[0-9]*/\1/g'
the temperature is 28.3 C°
```

but you probably don't want truncation.  Rounding is probably more appropriate, in which case:

```
$ echo "the temperature is 28.37567 C°" | awk '{$4 = sprintf("%.1f", $4)}1'
the temperature is 28.4 C°
```

but that's pretty fragile in matching the 4th field.  You could add a loop to check all the fields, but this gives the idea.  Also note that `awk` will squeeze all your whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

2 brute force ways, depending on whether u wanna keep the celsius sign or not :

> ```
> mawk '$!_=int(10*$_)/10' <<<'28.34567 C°'
> ```

28.3 C°

> ```
> mawk '$!NF=int(10*$_)/10' <<<'28.34567 C°'
> ```

28.3